# Case statement issue in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Here is the part of my select query that I am trying to use the case statement

```
CASE SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResStatus
   WHEN 'X' THEN CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePrice', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
           + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceTax', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
           + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceGST', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
       as total                       
   ELSE  (SUM(SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePrice + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceTax + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceGST)  as total
END
```

And this is the entire query

```
SELECT     
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResNumber, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.LeadName, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.NoPax, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.MarketCode, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResProductCode, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResTourCode, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.SellMethod, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.DepDate, 
    CONVERT(datetime, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.BookDate, 101) AS bookdate, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.BookedBy, 
    CASE SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResStatus
       WHEN 'X' THEN CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePrice', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
          + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceTax', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
          + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceGST', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
       ELSE  (SUM(SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePrice + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceTax + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceGST) 
    END,
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.Product.ProductName, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ParentResNumber, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResStatus, 
    dbo.ResItinerary_insurance.LocalCost * dbo.ResItinerary_insurance.Qty AS insurance
FROM         
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral 
INNER JOIN
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.Product ON SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResProductCode = SoftripNetTest.dbo.Product.ProductCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.ResItinerary_insurance ON SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResNumber = dbo.ResItinerary_insurance.ResNumber
WHERE     
    (SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.BookDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
GROUP BY 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResNumber, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.LeadName, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.NoPax, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.MarketCode, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResProductCode, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResTourCode, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.SellMethod, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.DepDate, $
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.BookDate, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.BookedBy, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.BookSource, SoftripNetTest.dbo.Product.ProductName, 
    SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ParentResNumber, SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResStatus,
```

I keep getting errors near the AS in my case statement? Can case statements be used in the middle of a query? I want the everything to be pulled the same way for both resstatus A and X except the total would this be the best way to do it? I am using fn_getxmlvalue which is a function, because the cancelled information is stored in xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `as total` alias after the `END` of the `CASE` statement.

```
         CASE SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResStatus
       WHEN 'X' THEN CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePrice', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
                          + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceTax', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
                          + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceGST', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
       ELSE  (SUM(SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePrice + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceTax + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceGST)
    END   as total
```

Comment: this worked great but i keep getting an ambiguous column name at additionaldata

Answer (score 2):

```
         CASE SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.ResStatus
       WHEN 'X' THEN CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePrice', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
                          + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceTax', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
                          + CAST(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(SoftripNetTest.dbo.fn_GetXMLValue(AdditionalData, 'HeaderCancellationData', ''), 'TotalQuotePriceGST', 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 

       ELSE  (SUM(SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePrice + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceTax + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceGST)  as total
    END 
    as total
```

You can't name individual parts of the case statement, but you can name the outcome column, just move your name to the end of the case statement

Comment: this worked great but i keep getting an ambiguous column name at additionaldata

Comment: prefix it with the table name like `table.columnname` or `derivedtable.columnname`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `as total` in the middle of the `CASE`.

The `CASE` statement will output one field at the end, and you name it **AFTER THE END**:

```
CASE WHEN ...
     WHEN ...
     ELSE ...
END as 'Blah'
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the  "as total" alias from the following line:

```
ELSE  (SUM(SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePrice + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceTax + SoftripNetTest.dbo.ResGeneral.TTlQuotePriceGST)  as total
        END
```